# Best cloud platform for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, cloud

Currently, in our project, we use dedicated servers for our PostgreSQL database.

In theory, we can run anything on some cloud platforms. However, PostgreSQL configuration is strictly related to hardware configuration. What we are looking for is a cloud solution with native PostgreSQL support.

Here is the list of desired features:

- automatic database configuration adjustment depending on selected resources
- replication setup out of the box

So what are the options and the best pick for such a service?

Comment: Googling "Postgresql Cloud" yields a few more hits, including http://www.cloudpostgres.com/ (I'm not affiliated with them in any way).

Comment: As of Sep'13, this is on the front page of `postgresql` tag with 14 upvotes. From the answers, it seems that Heroku is the only popular choice with AWS+Postgre Plus Cloud being a distant second.

Comment: Try Database Labs: https://www.databaselabs.io/

Answer (score 6):

Heroku has the features you require:

https://postgres.heroku.com/

Answer (score 6):

First, in general, if you have dedicated servers, I think you are usually better off using them.  Through a [business](http://www.efficito.com) that does hosting for a PostgreSQL-backed ERP, I am relatively aware of what the problems are.  For us, replication is more or less set up out of the box but tuning the db is problematic.  I would expect that [2ndQuadrant's](http://www.2ndquadrant.com) hosting (which I think is dedicated server if I understand correctly) to be able to set up and things for you, but I am not sure what the package would cost.

At Efficito, we set up replication by default since we use it for taking base backups (pg_basebackup requires that replication is enabled and continuous archiving configured).  This being said, that's the easy part.

Auto-configuration for performance tuning and resources is a big difficulty.  This is dependent, honestly, not only on resources available but on query profiles. Things like effective cache size can be changed, but what about shared_buffers?  Increasing this can have a negative impact on database performance in some cases.

One huge issue with cloud hosting though is that it is far harder to guarantee the performance required than it is with dedicated hardware.  If dedicated hardware is an option, go with it (and if you need hosting/management, contact 2ndQuadrant).  If you really need cloud hosting, consider the options by others.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku have a very simple and quick interface for creating PostgreSQL databases, but you might find that the options are limited. AFAIK you get a single user account, and because the system is shared there are limitations on what you can tweak. For the most part you get to choose the memory allocaton, and this is what they charge by. You are limited in the extensions you can use, and they do not currently support foreign data wrappers for example.

Setting up databases and follower databases is trivially simple however, and upgrading between plans is simple.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [EnterpriseDB cloud-database](http://enterprisedb.com/cloud-database) - they offer pre-built AWS and HP Cloud setups which include support.

[Rackspace knowledgebase](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-intrepd-postgresql-install) has steps for installing postgresql, although they only provide database support for mysql, SQL server and Oracle.

The [OpenStack documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/setting-up-sql-database-postgresql.html) also includes steps for installing postgresql.

EDIT: 2013-11-16

Amazon RDS would now be the best choice here - they now offer postgresql instances within their RDS offerings. This brings postgresql into line with features offered by mysql RDS setups including the 88 ECUs with 244 GB option which isn't available to oracle or mysql server RDS setups. [AWS RDS for PostgreSQL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/)

Answer (score 2):

You can research "ashnik" ([EnterpriseDB - The Postgres Database Company](http://www.enterprisedb.com/)) - Ashnik enables enterprises adopt open source software solution with confidence

For information, you can view this link: 
[Enterprisedb Ashnik](http://www.ashnik.com/)